# Removing special characters in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have found information on how this could be done, but nothing has worked for me. I am trying to replace the special character 'ð'. I imported my data from a csv file and I used encoding='latin1' or else I kept getting errors. However, a simple DF['Column'].str.replace('ð', '') will not do the trick. I also tried decoding and using the hex value for that character which was recommended on another post, but that still won't work for me. Help is very much appreciated, and I am willing to post code if necessary.

Answer (score 13):

Call `str.encode` followed by `str.decode`:

```
df.YourCol.str.encode('utf-8').str.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

If you want to do this for multiple columns, you can slice and call `df.applymap`:

```
df[col_list].applymap(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Remember that these operations are not in-place. So, you'll have to assign those columns back to their rightful place.

Comment: Thank you! What does that do exactly? I want to specifically only get rid of 'ð' and nothing else.

Comment: It purges your dataframe of every non-ascii or accentuated character.

Comment: You have no idea how this solution has helped me :D